# Enumerating all parse trees from a parse forest

Tags: parsing

Say a generalized parsing algorithm whether a GLL parser or Early parser generates a parse forest. Would it be possible to enumerate all of the parse trees from the forest? If possible, in a lazy matter?

Comment: Tom Ridge's work [Simple, functional, sound and complete parsing
for all context-free grammars](http://www.tom-ridge.com/oldsite/resources/doc/ridge11parsing-cpp.pdf) could be of interest.